# How to prevent installing documentation for gems automatically using gem v. 2.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-2.0

Previously set up my system to suppress installing gem documentation with `--no-ri` and `--no-rdoc`.

Ruby 2.0.0 and gem 2.0.0 seems to have removed the `--no-ri` flag (and functionality?).

Even when specifying `--no-rdoc`, I still get `installing documentation`:

```
~/dev/ruby> gem install bundler --no-rdoc
Fetching: bundler-1.3.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.1
Done installing documentation for bundler (0 sec).
```

How to see whether or not documentation is installed? If it is installed, how to suppress for all gem installs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As `gem help install` states:

```
Usage: gem install GEMNAME [GEMNAME ...] [options] -- --build-flags [options]
...
  Install/Update Options:
    ...
        --[no-]document [TYPES]      Generate documentation for installed gems
                                     List the documentation types you wish to
                                     generate.  For example: rdoc,ri
    -N, --no-document                Disable documentation generation
```

In short:

- `--no-rdoc` is now `--no-document rdoc`
- `--no-ri` is now `--no-document ri`.
- You can prevent both from installing with either `--no-document` or `-N`.

(Unfortunately as of this writing the [documentation on Rubygems.org](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_install) is currently out-of-date, so ignore that for now.)

Answer (score 6):

The option has changed to `--no-document` (see http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/History_txt.html)